# Save both 'id' and 'name' in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Working with a project using Angular 5, Material component and Firebase. Is it possible to store two values via one field.
Below is my code i get data from client table and show names in dropdown but store "client_id". i wanna store client_name also with client_id.

```
<mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder=" Select Client" formControlName="client_id" required>
               <mat-option *ngFor="let cli of clientsarray; let i = index " [value]="cli.prodid">{{cli.fname}} {{cli.lname}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: instead of `[value]="cli.prodid"` use the whole client object `[value]="cli"`

Comment: @JasonWhite its work properly but having bit confusion I have already client table where whole information of client is already stored. Is this good approach to store whole data in another table.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind to an object, `cli` in this case.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let cli of clientsarray; let i = index " [value]="cli">{{cli.fname}} {{cli.lname}}</mat-option>
```

Comment: After getting response, if value becomes object then how to display selected value ?

Comment: @AniketAvhad - I am not sure what you mean? You can bind the `mat-select` control using `[(ngModel)]` (like any other control) to set the selected value (object). Then you use it like anything else in the component.

Comment: See the actual problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjqqcb?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts....here if i set [value]= "obj"  and  assign a id to selected variable then it will not display first option as selected.

Comment: @AniketAvhad - you have to treat it like an object. See your updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjqqcb-ab83tm